# Getting RowCount without wasting resources

Tags: programming-practices, sql, efficiency

I have a large SQL query that relates 6-7 different tables and returns fourteen different rows as distinct sets, in a union with an equally-large query, that at times can return over a thousand results.

Luckily for us, we have the option to simply return the first 100 results of that query, which significantly reduces its processing time.

However, we also need an exact *count* of that query, which we've only managed to get by querying the *entire* set, and when we hit the larger return sets, it causes our app to hang.

This is hugely inefficient, on top of which the real issue is our count query - it is basically the exact same query, but instead of returning the distinct rows, it's just returning a count of those rows!

We can't filter out our tables or our return values - because they are a distinct set, they change the row count.  But we can't run this query twice in a row just to get the number of rows we're expecting, with the rowcount being the *more* cumbersome of the two each time.

There has to be a better way - how can I get my SQL to return a rowcount of a large query, without wasting the resources of that query?

Comment: This feels a bit unclear currently, but if it is clarified would be a better question for Stack Overflow (or potentially, if you added your query, Code Review).

Comment: The DBA wizards over at dba.stackexchange.com can probably give you the best answer.

Comment: For both of them, I would have to first rewrite the entire 75-line query to have non-sensitive aliases and DB Schemas so that they could poke at it, and then I would probably just be told that there's other problems with the query, without ever getting an actual answer to the question I'm really asking - What's the most efficient way to get a Rowcount for a complex query?

Comment: @Poke If you feel that dba.se would be a better fit for this question, I'll move it over there. But I don't think this belongs on SO - they deal with pretty specific coding problems (I think?), and this is more of a general practice question.

Comment: It seems non-sensical to have to do the count without needing the data but ultimately it is a set operation so the figure will need to be calculated. As a first port of call I'd look at making sure you don't have stale stats and run it thru an index analyzer.

Comment: @Zibbobz Incidentally, there is no silver bullet for these sorts of questions without seeing the query, the data, the stats, the configuration, the execution plan and the hardware. Suggestions can only be speculative at best. To cut a long story short - speak to your DBA.

Comment: Are you concerned with the processing to generate the result set within the DB server, or handling the result set within your application? mysql_store_result vs mysql_use_result may help - and it wouldn't hurt to know what language you're using. And to clarify if indeed "My SQL" is mysql, or just your SQL

Comment: Why do you need an exact count?  You might be able to get away with selecting the top 101 records, returning the top 100, and reporting "there are more records that match your parameters - please refine your query"

Comment: @Dan Not a bad idea, but I'll definitely have to run that by my boss.

Comment: @PhilLello The first one - storing the results isn't a huge problem, it's the query itself that hangs.

Comment: @Zibbobz without knowing what 'explain plan' reveals, it is very hard to say why that is the case.

Comment: At the very least, to avoid running the joins twice, you could query the entire result set, store it in a table variable, and then return the count and the top 100 rows.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the precise count of the records, there's little you can do but to actually run the same whole query. Data fetching is likely not the heaviest part of the query, joins are. (Were it not so, `select count(*)...` would be fast and you'd use it.)

You can speed up the query in various ways. It's hard to say anything without seeing the query and the query plan.

If there is a heavyweight join (or a cluster of them) that does not depend from (most of) the rest of the query, you could create an auxiliary table with its results pre-computed and use in your join instead. You'd likely need a trigger or a batch job to update it, or use a materialized view if your DBMS supports them.

If the pre-computed subquery table is not updated immediately with every update of the tables involved in the subquery, you could possibly by content with the *approximate* results, and recompute the data e.g. once a minute or once a hour.

Answer (score 2):

If the query is a canned query that doesn't take any parameters and the results don't change often, you could consider running it during non-peak times and cacheing the result to use later. If you do use parameters and retrieve different result sets, then you could look at the query and see if there are any static portions and consider creating the view to encapsulate those parts; a good RDBMS will cache the view results so you don't have to re-execute those parts of the query again. If you can't do either of those things, then the best advice I can give is to go ahead and return all the results all the time and simply count the rows from the resultset. At least then you don't have to run the query twice.

Answer (score -4):

Use the COUNT aggregate function in your query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'row_count', * FROM Table WHERE [...]
```

The COUNT function is standard in most SQL databases.

Comment: I don't think the OP is actually struggling with the count part. They're just trying to pull the count without running the main body of the data fetch query...